# insted of "autoload_server" I want to use "server_document"

Tags: python-3.x, flask, bokeh

I want to make bokeh embedded web app.

resources said "autoload_server" works but it does not.

```
session=pull_session(url=url,app_path="/random_generator")
bokeh_script=autoload_server(None,app_path="/random_generator",session_id=session.id, url=url)
```

I think autoload_server can not be used anymore 
so instead of this, I want to use server_document

I wrote this code but still does not work
how should I write this code?

```
 session=pull_session(url=url,app_path="/random_generator")
    bokeh_script=server_document("/random_generator")
```

Answer (score 0):

`server_document` is for creating and embedding *new sessions* from a Bokeh server. It is not useful for interacting with already existing sessions, i.e. it is not useful together with `pull_session`. For that, you want to use `server_session`, as [described in the documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library). For example, in a Flask app you would have something like:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def bkapp_page():

    with pull_session(url="http://localhost:5006/sliders") as session:

        # update or customize that session
        session.document.roots[0].children[1].title.text = "Special Sliders!"

        # generate a script to load the customized session
        script = server_session(session_id=session.id,
                                url='http://localhost:5006/sliders')

        # use the script in the rendered page
        return render_template("embed.html", script=script, template="Flask")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Please give me one more advice.
I want to use this as web apps so after "url= " I do not know how to write

Your answer is for local base
(url="http://localhost:5006/sliders")

So when it comes to making it for web apps it should be like this?? 
(url="http://123.12.123.123/sliders")

Thank you

Comment: It just needs to be the full URL to the zoo, whatever that is.

Comment: I adopted the given code for my program.
but still, have an error         
"bokeh_serve: ERROR (spawn error)"

Could you please teach me what's wrong with my code
Thank you.

----------------------------------------------------
    with pull_session(url="http://160.16.225.109/opt/webapps/bokehflask/random_generator") as session:
        script = server_session(session_id=session.id,
                                url='http://160.16.225.109/opt/webapps/bokehflask/random_generator')
        return render_template("index.html", bokeh_script=script)

Comment: That error message is not coming from bokeh. Perhaps some process manager you are using? I don't have any further advice to give.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see other possibilities.
Thank you very much.